# How to get an image into react native from api?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native, image

I'm making an app with React Native where I display F1 cars as a school project and I get my data(titles, images,..) from posts on my Wordpress website. I'm doing this using fetch. (Note: I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if my wording is a bit complicated.)

I!m using postman to find my data and I found my image that I want to use:

```
"og_image": [
            {
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080,
                "url": "https://tibomertens.be/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/F1-75_JPG_SPONSOR_00004.jpg",
                "type": "image/jpeg"
            }
        ],
```

So in my React Native code I wrote this to get the image url:

```
{item.id === 572 && (
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 200 }}
                  source={{ uri: `${item.og_image[0].url}` }}
                />
              )}
```

But it gives an error "[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.og_image[2]')]".

full code:

```
const Cars = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [Cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  const getCars = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://tibomertens.be/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=8",
        {}
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setCars(json);
      console.log(Cars);
      console.log("hey");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCars();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={Cars}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>
              {"\n"}
              {item.id === 572 && (
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 200 }}
                  source={{ uri: `${item.og_image[0].url}` }}
                />
              )}
              <Text>
                {item.title.rendered} {"\n"}{" "}
              </Text>
              <Text>{item.rttpg_excerpt}</Text>
            </Text>
            <Pressable
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("Details", {
                  itemTile: item.title.rendered,
                })
              }
            >
              <Text>bekijk product</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        )}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Thanks for reading and hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct way to access the image url? From what you posted, it would be `item.og_image[0].url`

Comment: Abe, this gives [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.og_image[0]') when I try it

Comment: Try logging out the `item` from your renderItem callback and see what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated answer. Change this code:

```
{item.id === 572 && (
    <Image
       style={{ width: 50, height: 200 }}
       source={{ uri: `${item.og_image[0].url}` }}
         />
   )}
```

to:

```
{item.yoast_head_json?.og_image !== undefined && <Image
  style={{ width: 50, height: 200 }}
  source={{ uri: `${item.yoast_head_json.og_image[0].url}` }}
/>
}
```

Comment: Hey Raziel, This gives an error "[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.og_image[0]')". Any idea why?

Comment: thats because og_image only exists within the id 572. Check out updated answer

Comment: Sadly, this gives me the same error :/

Comment: can you post the updated code in your original question

Comment: I updated my original question

Comment: try the updated answeer